# Mulesoft filecopy not working when invoked via http adapter

Tags: mule, adapter

I am trying to copy file from one local folder to another when invoked via some http url but it is not working. In my destination folder some garbage file is getting created with .dat extension

Source folder - so1

Destination folder - so2

This is the message i get in the mule console on invoking the http endpoint

```
INFO  2017-10-27 14:02:45,346 [[each].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'File.dispatcher.33168380'. Object is: FileMessageDispatcher

INFO  2017-10-27 14:02:45,467 [[each].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'File.dispatcher.33168380'. Object is: FileMessageDispatcher

INFO  2017-10-27 14:02:45,488 [[each].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileConnector: Writing file to: D:\so2\681cebe0-baf1-11e7-9534-0c7b20524153.dat
```

Here is the configuration XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
                        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
                        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
                        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd">

    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />
    <file:connector name="File" writeToDirectory="D:\so2" readFromDirectory="D:\so1" autoDelete="false" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File" />
    <flow name="eachFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/copy" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="D:\so1" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" />
        <set-payload value="files copied" doc:name="Set Payload" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No where your are reading the file in your configuration.

In your scenario, the file outbound endpoint just creates a new file with null payload with unknown file extension.

You can do in two ways,

1) Instead of HTTP inbound, you can use file inbound to read the file and then copy.

2) If you have to use HTTP inbound to copy the file on demand, use mule requester component in middle of configuration to read the file and then copy.

How to use mule requester, you can check here https://www.ricston.com/blog/reading-file-middle-flow-mule-requester/

**UPDATE:**

See the below configuration to read all the files from one folder and to copy to another folder using Mule requester.

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
    host="localhost" port="8086" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />
<file:connector name="File" 
     autoDelete="true" streaming="false"
    validateConnections="true" doc:name="File" moveToDirectory="C:\FilePOC\so2"/>
<flow name="Flow1">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
        path="/copy" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <mulerequester:request-collection resource="file:///C:/FilePOC/so1?connector=File" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
    <set-payload value="File copy has been successful." doc:name="Set Payload"/>
</flow>
```

Here, no need to use the File outbound component to copy the files. The **moveToDirectory** option on File connector moves the file once the file has been read.

The other example on how to use Mule requester with JMS can be found here https://www.slideshare.net/anir37/using-mule-requester-for-jms

Comment: Hi i went through the blog but since I am new to mulesoft I could not understand how to use the mule requester. In the example i saw you are reading only one file..If you have any example on how to read all files from the source folder and how to copy to the destination it would be very helpful.. Also if you have other use cases of using this mule requestor it would be great..i was able to import the mule requestor component in my ide.. thanks !

Comment: Please accept my answer and close the question if it helped @user3428616